# Capacitor after regulator

Tags: capacitor, ldo, linear-regulator

I want to use a LM2940 regulator.
From the datasheet [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2940-n.pdf) , I can see that it needs a 22uf polorized capacitorfor Vout.
However the regulator is place before a 470uf tantalum capacitor, do I need to put the 22uf then the 470uf or can I just use the 470uf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the DS says about the capacitor: -

> **COUT must be at least 22 μF to maintain stability. May be increased without bound to maintain regulation during transients. Locate as
>   close as possible to the regulator. This capacitor must be rated over
>   the same operating temperature range as the regulator and the ESR is
>   critical; see curve

The curve referred to is figure 20.

So, if the 470 uF is fairly close then no problem. See also section 8.2.2.1.2 ESR Limits